# Android JNI basic application gives Exceptions while running- java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError, java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I'm following a basic tutorial for the android jni development at http://permadi.com/blog/2011/12/running-android-ndk-examples-using-eclipse-and-sequoyah/. Before moving to problem I solved building error by setting "cmd F:\Android\android-ndk-r8\ndk-build" to build command.

Changed build command
[image: Changed build command]

Hope it's not wrong. But now it gives following error. Iv'e added logcat here.
[image: Logcat]

I can see two exceptions are shown here as java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError and java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError. I can't figure out what is really caused. It is said that you can fix UnsatisfiedLinkError by adding libJniTest.so to correct path. But i can't find it. I've run a search on my windows machine to find libjnitest.so but it is nowhere. Is it the problem and if it is someone can say where it should be. There are more than thousand questions as same as this but i'm no where to figure it out solution after spending several hours.

Here is my code.
Java code
[image: Java code]
Please note that iv'e commented native function call but i can see problem is with the loading library.
Native code
[image: Native code]

Here i add the folder structure.

[image]

Comment: What's your project structure? Where is JniTest.cpp located?

Comment: When you compile your native code you should have a .so file, you need to add this to the libs folder in your project structure.

Comment: alternatively try this tutorial  http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run $(NDK)/ndk-build from the project's main directory in order to create the .so libraries, which should be automatically copied into the libs/ folder.

This assumes that you have a proper jni/ folder with an Android.mk in it alongside your source code.

You may want to see the hello-jni example from the ndk samples directory for an official example with all the requried pieces.

Comment: When i use default build command after setting path variable to F:\Android\android-ndk-r8\ (where i put ndk) it gives me following error. I solved it by adding command as shown in the problem (i added new image). Is it wrong? Yes i can see my lib folder is empty.

Comment: If your libs folder is empty you are either not running the build command, or it is failing.  Try running ndk-build from a terminal, and make sure that you do so from the app's top directory, ie jni/ should be a subdirectory the directory you run ndk-build in.

Comment: thats the reason you are getting the error , try running ndk-build from your project directory

Comment: When i not default command i get this error.
**** Build of configuration Default for project JniTest ****

ndk-build V=1 

Error: Cannot run program "ndk-build": Launching failed

**** Build Finished ****

Comment: Please run it in a **terminal** as directed.

Comment: Yes it works. Thanks  Chris Stratton. Just to know isn't there a way to do this with eclipse. Getting know that may helpful to all.

Comment: There's probably a way to configure the command execution directory.  Or you could try a composite command like cd [some representation of project directory] ; [ndk path]/ndk-build but don't know if windows supports that.  Or you could make the command be a .bat file.

Answer (score 0):

Clean and build the project again. It will be resolved. I solved it by just that.